# Need help for Regex in PHP, identifying similar words

Tags: php, regex, count, keyword

I give an example to easily describe the problem.

Input text:
**Wayne Rooney** is an English footballer who plays as a striker for Manchester United. **Rooney** became the youngest player to play for England when he earned his first cap in a friendly against Australia. Theo Walcott broke **Rooney's** appearance record by 36 days in May 2006.

Input keyword: wayne rooney

Expected output (keyword count): 3 (wayne rooney, rooney, rooney's)

So, it doesn't only count "wayne rooney", but also other similar words.

I have searching over SO, I got this regex:

```
$keyword_count = preg_match_all("/(\w*(?:wayne|rooney)\w*)/i", $source, $res);
```

But it gives me 4 as the output. It counts "wayne rooney" as two different keywords.

Could anyone help me to construct the correct formula?
Is Regex really the most efficient solution for this? I have a high volume of text to search. Any other solution, for example Text Mining library for PHP?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The "extra" result is returned because you look for either 'wayne' or 'rooney' in your search (the | character). Try it out by replacing the 'wayne|' part with something like '(wayne\s*)?'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
(?i)(\b(?:wayne(?:'s)?\s*)?rooney(?:'s)?\b)
```

If you have limited count of regular rules to parse string, regex is appropriate to solve your problem. In general case you should use other methods (may be several regex).

Comment: Better ask the OP if "Wayne" by itself is needed.  If so, your solution will need an easy edit. :)

Comment: thanks for sharing, but this regex is sufficient for me: `/(\w*(?:(wayne\s*)?rooney)\w*)/i`

Comment: @tukang-coding, I updated my answer. It is your solution simply modified: added word boundaries (`\b`), added match to char `'`, e.g.:  `Rooney's`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could be helpful or an alternative to regex:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

Comment: I've been look around on this function, but I think it requires lot of computation because I need to compare one by one between the keyword and the similar words.

Answer (score 0):

For this special case you can do something like this

```
Wayne(?:\sRooney[\w']*)?|Rooney[\w']*
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2ua5k)

It says: Search for `Wayne Rooney` OR `Rooney` (each can be followed by `[\w']*`), but for the first part the `(?:\sRooney[\w']*)?` is optional.

Comment: thanks, I found this Regex from @Uphill_ What '1 also work: `/(\w*(?:(wayne\s*)?rooney)\w*)/i`

Answer (score 0):

Are you are simply trying to match a single known name from a piece of text, or are you actually trying to identify something matching "known people" or "names"?

If the latter then you could be using something like [OpenCalais](http://www.opencalais.com/) constrained to a known type 'people' (who knows, maybe there is a 'footballers' taxonomy).

Here is an [analysis of similar](http://blog.viewchange.org/2010/05/entity-extraction-content-api-evaluation/) tools.

Comment: Given a keyword which is likely to be a famous name, I need to count it's occurrence in a given text.  Thanks for pointing me to those analysis tools. They look so promising, I need to try them.